# Why doesn't the width (or max-width) property apply to my divs?

Tags: html, css, width

**[JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/zymjo5y3/)**

I want the explicit width of `240px` for my `.left` and `.right` `div`s. I tried this with `width` and `max-width`, as well as using `span`s instead of `div`s, didn't work.

I am at a loss to understand why doesn't it apply at all, while a fixed width of `600px` obediently applied to the `.wrapper` div.

Can I be told why this is happening, and what should I do?

***HTML:***

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">
        UGH
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        AGH
    </div>
</div>
```

***CSS:***

```
.wrapper{
    width:600px;
    background-color:red;
    padding: 0 50px 0 50px;
}
.left{
    display:inline;
    background-color:pink;
    max-width:240px;
    margin-right:10px;
}
.right{
    display:inline;
    background-color:grey;
    max-width:240px;
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are inline, and have the width same as their content.

If you want ot set them width, change `display: inline` them to `inline-block` or set `float`.

Answer (score 3):

`Inline` elements do not use properties such as `width` or `height` unlike block elements. This does the job, adjust the margins then to your likings.

```
display:inline-block;
width:240px;
```

The width has to be explicitly set, otherwise a `block`-type element inherits it from a parent element. You can use `max-width` additionally then.

Answer (score 2):

It is because you're using inline for the div and inline element can't have width.

So, just set them `inline-block;`

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: block;` and `float: left;` (left or right).

Or use `diplay: inline-block;`

Comment: `Display: block` is the default value and floating elements are block without need to declare that.

Answer (score 0):

You have padding and margins to consider, If everything adds up to more than the container, it's cause mis-alignments. `inline` and `inline-block` work to line elements but ultimately they don't work for every browser. I find it's best to use the oldest method in the book! `float`.

```
.wrapper{
    width:600px;
    background:#FF0000;
    padding:0 50px;
}
.left,.right{
    width:240px;
    margin:0 5px;
    float:left;
}
.clear{
    clear:both;//when using float we need to clear the floating space. Or something? 
}
```

So after all your floating elements, add this element:

```
<div class='clear'></div>
```

Just make sure you don't go out of your 100%. 600=100%. Going over 100% = mis-alignments. Including `border:1px solid #FF0000;` which makes 2px.

Comment: It isn't about wrong widths due to margin and padding: it's ignored, because of inline. Also why use an extra element when you can add a [clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) on parent?

Comment: @FelipeAls because the parent will collapse, unless you have a better alternative? Plus! 100% can also cause the inline-block to not be inline.

Comment: That's also what a clearfix does: containing floats, without the extra element

Comment: @FelipeAls ohh ok :) so `clearfix:both;` can go in the parent or in this case: `.wrapper`?